# Error CS0407 'string Form1.Form1_Load(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Please help me with this error message:

> a cs0161 Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0407  'string Form1.Form1_Load(object, EventArgs)' has the wrong return type  homework v2 C:\Users\harry\source\repos\homework v2\homework v2\Form1.Designer.cs   137 Active

```
private string Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label3.Show();
    button2.Hide();
    label3.Text = name_1.Text;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Hide();
    label2.Hide();
    button1.Hide();
    button2.Show();
    label3.Show();
}
```

Comment: `private string Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`  → Event handler should return void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method:

```
private string Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label3.Show();
    button2.Hide();
    label3.Text = name_1.Text;
}
```

has a return type of `string`. The error message says that this method has the wrong return type.  Consider changing the method to be `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` so that its return type is `void`.

Also, if the return type were `string`, then there needs to be a line within the method that returns a string, which there isn't at the moment.